# Short story about an author living in a Gothic horror who writes fantasy about our world

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Saw this online years ago, possibly even on this site.  It was a short story about an author who lived in a classic Gothic horror world (forests were always dark and always had maidens fleeing through them, and so forth).  He was trying to write "realistic fiction," and nobody wanted to read it.  Eventually, he broke down and wrote some "fantasy," which, for him, was a story about a woman standing by a kitchen sink while her husband read a newspaper and realizing she either no longer loved him or never really had.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You suggest you might have read it here; does that mean you've only read a summary of the story, or that you found a link to it here?  Approximately how many years ago?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Found it!  It's Neil Gaiman's *Forbidden Brides of the Faceless Slaves in the Secret House of the Night of Dread Desire*, which was first published in 2004 in a [prose](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?869926) version and in 2017 in a [graphic](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?2110877) edition.

The prose version can be read in [*Gothic!*](https://archive.org/details/gothic0000unse_d9f5/page/90/mode/2up) or [*Fantasy: the best of 2004*](https://archive.org/details/fantasybestof2000000unse/page/n13/mode/2up) borrowed from the Internet Archive.

Comment: Well done. We'd be grateful if you'd mark your answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which is this site's way of showing that a query has been solved to the OP's satisfaction. You can mark an answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, however, as this is a self-answer, you'll need to wait until 48 hours have elapsed since the question was initially posted.

Comment: Also collected in Fragile Things.